# Таймер (NSTimer) iOS

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone, objective-c

Добрый день, у меня тут задачка, а я не знаю как с ней справиться.

У меня есть действие, которое выполняется: например, рисует картинку сразу при открытии страницы. 
Как мне таймером указать, чтоб отрисовка началась через 5 секунд?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можешь сделать приватный метод и вызвать через селектор с задержкой

```
[self performSelector:@selector(privateMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

Comment: Мне сказали что можно сделать все просто NSTimer *123 = [NSTimer ......] вот только я не совсем пойму как

Comment: Мне кажется мой вариант проще :)
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/scheduledTimerWithTimeIntervalExample.html
Пример именно с invocation:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1449106/887325

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать !!!

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный вариант через GCD:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5*NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    <код>
});
```